# Mix 2 arrays using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I need to intersect 2 arrays (`List<T>`) by keeping just the distinct elements and mix the elements of one array with the other like this:

```
    A1 B1 C1 D1
    W2 X2 Y2 Z2 
 => A1 W2 B1 X2 C1 Y2 D1 Z2


    A1 B1 A1 D1
    W2 X2 Y2 Z2 
 => A1 W2 B1 X2 Y2 D1 Z2 // repeating A1


    A1 B1 A1 D1
    Z2 X2 Y2 Z2 
 => A1 Z2 B1 X2 Y2 D1  // repeating A1, Z2

    A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
    Z2 X2 Y2 
 => A1 Z2 B1 X2 C1 Y2 D1 E1
```

What is the optimal LINQ query to do it?

Comment: That doesn't look like an intersection in any normal sense...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Edited to 'Mix' + added different array sizes.

Comment: Just to reiterate, a `List<T>` isn't an array. I think you're trying to refer to the general concept of a *sequence*.

Comment: @Jon: let it be *sequence*, if you want. I don't think this is really important for the topic.

Comment: Clarity of expression is always, important, IMO. It's really worth knowing the meaning of different terms and using them appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interleave extension method (replaces `Zip`/`SelectMany` in Jon Skeets version). This may be a little faster and it includes the remaining of the longest list if the lists aren't of equal length:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Interleave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    var e0 = first.GetEnumerator();
    var e1 = second.GetEnumerator();

    bool e0HasValue = false;
    bool e1HasValue = false;

    // Could be made a little faster by not checking both when one is empty
    while ((e0HasValue = e0.MoveNext()) | (e1HasValue = e1.MoveNext()))
    {
        if (e0HasValue)
            yield return e0.Current;

        if (e1HasValue)
            yield return e1.Current;
    }
}
```

And if you want distinct items, use:

```
var result = firstList.Interleave(secondList).Distinct();
```

This answer, of cause, doesn't solve the uncertainty about `Distinct` as described in comments to Jon Skeet´s answer. But it could be combined with Jon Skeet´s order preserving extension method.

Answer (score 4):

(Note that `List<T>` is *not* an array, by the way.)

Well, I *think* this will do what you want, if you're using .NET 4 - and assuming the arrays are the same length:

```
var query = first.Zip(second, (x, y) => new[] { x, y })
                 .SelectMany(pair => pair)
                 .Distinct();
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the ordering of `Distinct` is *not* guaranteed. However, I expect it to actually stay the same in practice... given other changes I've suggested which affect observable results only in a *positive* (and tiny) way, I can't imagine this is going to change.

lasseespeholt's solution deals with the interleaving part. If you want absolutely *guaranteed* ordering, you can always implement Disrinct yourself, much like I did in Edulinq:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderPreservingDistinct<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.OrderPreservingDistinct(EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderPreservingDistinct<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return OrderPreservingDistinct(source, comparer ?? 
                                           EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderPreservingDistinct<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    HashSet<TSource> seenElements = new HashSet<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (seenElements.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var result = firstList.Interleave(secondList).OrderPreservingDistinct();
```

Comment: hm... if we suppress the constraint "the arrays are the same length", it changes something?

Comment: say, if the length are different I can always complete the smallest array with the last element to the length of the tallest...

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the order after Distinct() is _explicitly_ unspecified (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx) [paraphrasing you :)]

Comment: @serhio: It becomes trickier, because Zip will stop when the shorter list has finished.

Comment: respecting the order is important for me.

Comment: @serhio: The current implementation of Distinct() *does* preserve order, but it's just not *guaranteed* to.

Comment: does the Nathan's variant preserve the order?

Comment: @serhio: No, I don't believe so. Counterexample coming.

Comment: @serhio: No, absolutely not - you'd use lasseespeholt's answer for that, as specified in my answer. I saw no point in copying it into my answer.

Comment: Good work guys! Works like a charm. I hope you not mind if I mark as answer the lasseespeholt's reply ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not use only LINQ but i think use is simply and enough faster.

```
//List<string> l1 = new List<string>() { "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1" };
List<string> l1 = new List<string>() { "A1", "B1", "A1", "D1" };
//List<string> l2 = new List<string>() { "W2", "X2", "Y2", "Z2" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string>() { "Z2", "X2", "Y2", "Z2" };
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.AddRange(l1);
ls.AddRange(l2);
ls = ls.Distinct().ToList();
```